# Convert from base 10 to base 3

Tags: google-sheets, decimal, radix, base-conversion

I have a whole column in Google sheets with the numbers 1-400. Is there an easy way to convert these numbers to base 3?

Comment: What have you tried? It being in a column or being 1-400 doesn't sound relevant.

Comment: I have tried it manually but the column was to show that a single function won't work. It would be ideal if it was going to be quick for the whole column, not doing it individually.

Comment: Can you add the formula that you are using right now in to your question?

Comment: There is no formula to do base 3. I have no function at the moment and do not know where to start. Is there a macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a formula written in Apps Script:

```
function toTernary(decNumb) {
  var str = '';
  do {
    str = String(decNumb % 3) + str;
    decNumb = decNumb / 3 | 0;
  } while (decNumb >= 1);
  return parseInt(str);
}
```

Results:

[image: decimal to ternary apps script]

Usage:

1. Tools > Script Editor > Blank
2. Paste the code
3. Save the code file
4. Write the formula in your sheet as usual